# Parse codebird reply into a array (or acces to the json text into the codebird's reply)

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I am trying to use codebird to get some data from twitter. I have a script in JavaScript.
My problem is that codebird's reply is an object and not a JSON. So I can't use eval() to get parse the json text in an array.
I just need to acces the json data.

Thank you in advance

```
var cb = new Codebird();
cb.setConsumerKey("", "");
cb.setToken('','');  

cb.__call(
    "search_tweets",
    "q=Twitter",
     function (reply) {
    data = eval(reply) //parse the returned JSON to array
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a JavaScript object into a JSON string you can use

```
data = JSON.stringify(reply)
```

But usually it's better to deal with object itself - e.g. you can iterate thru it's properties (creating your own array if needed)

Comment: Thank you.
I will explore both idea.